# Sort list by values preserving names in R

Tags: r, sorting

Consider a list `l` like:

```
l<-list(a=24,b=12,c=30,d=1)
```

how to get the sorted version on values of such list, preserving names?

In result list the order of elements should be then: `d`,`b`,`a` and `c` corresponding to the sequence 1,12,24,30.

Comment: Or use a vector instead of a list if all its entries are numeric. `sort(unlist(l))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `order`.  Assuming that the length of each list element is 1 as showed in the example

```
l[order(unlist(l))]
```